# Edit Datagrid row

Tags: c#

how to edit a particular cell in a datagrid and accept data in that cell with textbox.the other cells in the datagrid need not to be editable
in C#.net 2005
thank s in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try it,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("No",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name");

dt.Rows.Add(1, "A");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "B");
dt.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;

dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
dataGridView1.DataSource =dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to update directly on the datagrid:

```
// Override the OnMouseClick event.
protected override void OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (base.DataGridView != null)
    {
        // Get the location (Row/Column) of the selected cell.
        Point point1 = base.DataGridView.CurrentCellAddress;
        // e.ColumnIndex/e.RowIndex can be replaced with a hard-coded
        // value if you only want a specific cell, row, or column to
        // be editable.
        if (point1.X == e.ColumnIndex &&
            point1.Y == e.RowIndex &&
            e.Button == MouseButtons.Left &&
            base.DataGridView.EditMode !=
            DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically)
        {
            // Open the cell to be edited.
            base.DataGridView.BeginEdit(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This will allow a user to edit the cell directly. If you hard-code a value in place of e.ColumnIndex, (example: hard code a 5), then only the 5th column will be editable. The same works for e.RowIndex.